# What is the best equivalent for FWIW in Russian?

Tags: перевод, выражения

I've seen the usage of English phrase *for what it's worth* many times.

However, I still don't know what the most precise translation of this phrase is in Russian.

Comment: My three cents, I am pretty sure you will get your question closed at the English usage Q&A if you ask anything related to translating from Russian to English. I believe anything tagged "english-to-russian" should not be allowed here either.

Comment: @bonomo: This is not really a translation question per se. I agree about removing the tag `english-to-russian`, but overall, I believe that the question is perfectly appropriate for RL&U.

Comment: @VisioN my English is not perfect so I can't get you the answer. But if you explain this phrase in few sentences instead of few words you will get more correct answer. Until now you have 2.5 different answers :)

Comment: The question is appropriate, according to the Definition phase questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No direct translation exists. '*For what it's worth*' usually means that whatever is to follow is going to be a subjective opinion, which translates well to

- *На мой взгляд* (*In my opinion*),
- *Я думаю* (*I think*),
- *Я считаю* (*I figure*).

If you want to communicate that a piece of information is potentially unimportant for another reason, you could say something like '*Может, это неважно, но*'.

Comment: Examples are mistranslated: “на мой взгляд” = “in my view” (“in my opinion” = “по моему мнению”), “я считаю” = “I figure” (literally: “to figure” = “to calculate”; “I think” = “я думаю”), “мне кажется” = “(it) seems to me (that)”.

Comment: @theUg if you take the expression literally, then they don't match perfectly, but if you consider their usage, they are spot on. +1 for alternative translations though, they could be useful.

Comment: There is no reason to fiddle with translation, when direct and literal one is available. Otherwise, it is confusing for everyone.

Comment: Another clarification as to why “я считаю” ≠ “I think”. “Cчитать” is closer in the figurative sense to the verb “to opine” (“I opine”) which is more assertive, whereas “I think” is more tentative (“I ponder that…” or “I am not sure, but I think that…”).

Comment: @theUg literal translations don't necessarily carry the intended meaning, "I ponder" is a great example of that. You can ponder something, but you can't say "I ponder" to express an opinion.

Comment: I said exactly that (“to ponder” is not a literal translation, by the way, ergo your argument is not cogent ;)). I just pointed that “I think” is a weak way of expressing an opinion. “I think” or “I reckon” are the ways to hedge your bets, not to assert a position. Although, come to think of it, the whole “я считаю” can be weak, so in this particular example I may well be wrong. Methinks.

Comment: @theUg I've chosen a poor example, but literal translations are still not the way to go, as [this joke](http://www.anekdot.ru:8084/id/-9947860/) illustrates.

Answer (score 5):

`FWIW` is roughly synonymous with `my two cents`, which can in turn be translated as `мои пять копеек`

**UPDATE:** Note that `мои пять копеек` is highly colloquial and can only really be met online.

Comment: Just my two cents: I've lived in Russia for 20 years, and I can't recall anyone using `просто мои пять копеек` in real life, except perhaps a couple of times in tech community where it is common to use loan translation of English phrases, or even no translation at all.

Comment: True, it's loan translation of the English phrase and never used in speech, but it's getting increasingly popular online, even outside of the tech community. The question asked about FWIW, which itself is only used online.

Comment: That's a valid point, thanks for elaborating.

Comment: @PhilipSeyfi I beg to differ, it seems to be fairly popular http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_What_It's_Worth

Comment: @PhilipSeyfi I bet the guys from Buffalo Springfield in 1966 had no idea about online chatting ;)

Comment: @VisioN & @kotekzot I bet they didn't use `FWIW` but `for what it's worth` in those days :P I've never seen FWIW in kind of a document, unlike `NB`, `BCC`, etc.

Comment: Question posed about translating a _phrase_, not a particular abbreviation. I reckon asker did it for the sake of keeping the length of the title manageable.

Comment: -1: idioms don't translate directly.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: You're right, they don't. `мои пять копеек` has neither the number 2, nor the word 'cents' in it. It is a version adapted to the Russian currency system and pops up regularly on internet forums and chats.

Comment: So it "Albanian language" (look it up). Does not make it proper Russian.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: I have never implied that `мои пять копеек` is proper literary Russian. Considering that we're looking for the best equivalent of `FWIW`, an acronym that itself is only used online, it should be clear enough that `мои пять копеек` or any equivalent thereof should not be used in speech or formal writing.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. If you just add some information which value you are not sure about, I would translate it as `на всякий случай`. If you express your opinion, you can add something like `я не настаиваю, но` or simply `я думаю`.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, на сколько это важно/полезно, но...

Может быть, это и не важно, но...

Answer (score 0):

"За что купил, за то и продаю"?

Comment: Это означает "передаю с чужих слов". А FWIW означает точку зрения с которой собеседник может не согласиться, а может и посчитать полезной.

Comment: Странно - везде в Интернете (кроме этого сайта) нахожу именно такой перевод.